# Convert Text to Numbers

Tags: sql, type-conversion

I've text in my database which I want to convert to unique numbers.

For example I've a coloumn with all seasons like winter, summer, autumn and spring.
Now I want for winter for example the number 1 for summer 2 and so on.

Can someone help me here? How can I solve it with SQL?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `CASE` expression, something like this:

```
SELECT
  CASE SeasonName
    WHEN 'Summer' THEN 1
    WHEN 'Winter' THEN 2
    WHEN 'Spring' THEN 3
    WHEN 'Fall' THEN 4
  END AS SeasonNumber
```

If you want to just convert all to random numbers, you can use a RANDOM() function, depending on your database.  Or you can use a window function to assign numbers to each row:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER()
```

This will assign an incremental integer value to each row.

**Updated**

```
SELECT SeasonName
FROM (
  SELECT
    CASE SeasonName
      WHEN 'Summer' THEN 1
      WHEN 'Winter' THEN 2
      WHEN 'Spring' THEN 3
      WHEN 'Fall' THEN 4
    END AS SeasonNumber
  FROM MyTable
) src
```

You can use the query above to use the aliased column expression by alias name.

Comment: Perfect is SeasonName the Column name? Because I get an error invalid column name.

Comment: In a way, yes.  SeasonName is an alias for the column expression.  If you want to refer to a derived column like this one in another part of your query, you may need to wrap the SELECT in another outer SELECT.  See updated example.

Comment: Perfect, thank you Ravioli. I don't know why, but I have to rename my column and now it works :)

Comment: I've one more question. Is it possible to do a Select * and your case statement in one query? So that i can get all data and the convert data from SeasonName?

Comment: Of course.  You can do something like this: `SELECT MyTable.*, CASE SeasonName ...`  If you want to reference the SeasonName alias elsewhere in your query, that's where you may need the outer SELECT.

Comment: You got it, my friend.